# How to stop div collapsing over other html content

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to code a website to have the main section fill 100% of the screen on all devices (i.e. the logo, navbar, slider and quote fill the whole screen, then you scroll down and the next section is 'Contact Me'). On my laptop screen and iPhone 6 it looks correct, but on smaller mobile screens (and when I resize my browser to a small size) the 'Contact Me' section seems to collapse over the other content.

I've tried setting a minimum width on the div (as that's what many of the suggestions seem to be) but with no luck.

I've attached a link to the website, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

http://176.32.230.9/andycheckcheck.co.uk/homepage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this CSS rule in there:

```
.firstSection {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EDF4ED;
}
```

Change `height` to `min-height` in there and add `height: 100%` to `body`:

```
.firstSection {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EDF4ED;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the words to collapse in the white space, I suggest adding a `white-space: nowrap` style to your `h2` "Contact Me" element.

CSS:

```
.nowrap {  
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h2 class="nowrap">Contact Me</h2>
```